# HowTo: Pass Windows user credentials of asp.net intranet user to WCF service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, authentication, intranet

#### I would like to pass the Windows credentials of the user using my ASP.NET MVC application to a WCF service. I want to achieve this via configuration only so that this happens transparently in code.

---

*(This question was originally asked in a too specific manner, as can be seen in the revisions. I only re-asked this in a better way to answer my own in hopes it might help someone. It turned out to be a pretty simple task).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the web.config (client and server), in the `<system.serviceModel>` section add/modify a binding to look something like this:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyBasicBinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

And, add this to client side web.config `<system.web>` section:

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

The two changes will make the end-user the current user of the web request which will then be sent in the WCF message.

The user can then be retrieved on the server side like this:

```
ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity
```